# Pagination for FooTable: a jQuery Plugin for Responsive Data Tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I want to add a pagination function for the [**FooTable: a jQuery Plugin for Responsive Data Tables**](http://css-tricks.com/footable-a-jquery-plugin-for-responsive-data-tables/) in css-tricks website.

Can anyone guide me how to apply pagination function in the above table.

Regards,
Dinesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this FooTable pagination [**DEMO**](http://fooplugins.com/footable/demos/paging.htm)

There are documentation and getting start guide for you to follow.